# AddRedirectToWww() redirecting to wrong domain

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm using the AddRedirectToWww rule for the rewriter middleware and I keep getting redirected to the wrong domain.

For context, my website is hosted on azure app service which has a default domain of myapp.azurewebsites.net. I have a custom domain say myapp.com and [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com).

I setup the rule so traffic from myapp.com gets redirect to [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com). However, what is happening is upon hitting myapp.com I get a redirect towards [www.myapp.azurewebsites.net](http://www.myapp.azurewebsites.net).

Any reason for why this is so? Does this middleware require specific request headers to determine the right host?

Answer (score 0):

From the scenario and configuration you described, it looks like you have not set CNAME and TXT record correctly. You need to configure this in your Domain Registrar/Provider.

You need to map a subdomain (for example, [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com)) by using a CNAME record.
Map a root domain (for example, myapp.com) by using an A record.

Kindly refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-your-domain) for step-step process.